# Trying to Shuffle a Deck of Cards and Mark them

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Im trying to make my code shuffle an initialized stack of cards (brand new pack of cards). I am able to actually shuffle the cards and store them in a new array. However, I am unsure how to mark the shuffled deck as cardInDeck = true.

```
struct CARD
{
    char cardSuit {};
    char cardFace {};
    int cardValue {};
    bool cardInDeck {};
    
    void printCard(){
        std::cout << cardFace << cardSuit << "\n";
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    const int numberOfCards {52};
    const int cardRank {13};
    const int numberOfSuits {4};
    
    CARD stackOfCards[numberOfCards];
    
    char cardSuit [] = {'H','S','C','D'};
    
    char cardFace [] = {'A', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'};
    
    int cardValue [] = {11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10};
   
    int k = 0;
    for(int suit = 0; suit < numberOfSuits; suit++)
    {
        for(int rank = 0; rank < cardRank; rank++)
        {
            //CARD temp;
            stackOfCards[k].cardSuit = cardSuit[suit];
            stackOfCards[k].cardFace = cardFace[rank];
            stackOfCards[k].cardValue = cardValue[rank];
            k++;
            
            int index = (13 * numberOfSuits) + cardRank - 1;
            stackOfCards[index].cardInDeck = false;
            
            //temp.cardInDeck = true;
        }
    } // end of card stack initializer
    
    srand(time(0));
    CARD shuffledDeck [numberOfCards];
    
    // Using a for loop to randomize the stack of cards and then inserting each card into a new array for shuffled cards
    for (int cardCounter = 0; cardCounter < numberOfCards; cardCounter++)
    {
        int randomNum =  rand() % 52;
        CARD temp = stackOfCards[cardCounter];
        shuffledDeck[cardCounter] = stackOfCards[randomNum];
        shuffledDeck[randomNum] = temp;
        
        //If statement checking the status of cardInDeck
        //If labeled as false (they all should be right now) they are then changed to true
        if (temp.cardInDeck == false)
        {
            stackOfCards[cardCounter].cardInDeck = true;
            stackOfCards[randomNum].cardInDeck = shuffledDeck[cardCounter].cardInDeck;
        }
        /*
        else
        {
            shuffledDeck[randomNum].cardInDeck = stackOfCards[cardCounter].cardInDeck;
            cardCounter ++;
        }
         */
    }
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and the most I've been able to do is marking all the cards in the stack as in the deck (cardInDeck = true), but I am unable to copy it into the deck at the current shuffled card number.

The goal is to check the in-deck status of the randomNum index in the stackOfCards array. If this card is marked as not in the deck (they all should be marked false) I need to mark it as in the deck. Then I need to copy it into the shuffledDeck at the current shuffled card number. When debugging I noticed that some cards (16) are marked as true while the rest are marked as false.

Comment: `int index = (13 * numberOfSuits) + cardRank - 1;` should be `int index = (13 * suit) + rank;`. I cannot figure out what your shuffle is trying to do, however.

Comment: I don't get `"but I am unable to copy it into the deck at the current shuffled card number."`. Please elaborate on what you expect and what you observed.

Comment: The goal of the shuffle is to take the initialized stank of cards, which goes in order by suit (Hearts, Spades, Clubs....) and then by face value (Ace,2,3,4...) and shuffle them into a new 'deck' in random order, as if you were to shuffle a deck of cards yourself.

Comment: by "but i am unable to copy it into the deck at the current shuffled card number" I mean basically that I have already set cardInDeck for the entire stackOfCards array to "true", I am trying to 'copy' this into the new array shuffledCards, after the cards have been inserted at random. I observed that this does not happen, and not all of the shuffledDeck array is set to 'true'.

Comment: A lot easier to use `std:shuffle`